# SharePoint access to the path is denied

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am getting an error in the Event viewer that says :

> Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\PowerPointConversion\86e05e4e-7f55-4093-b479-cae9e973883d\GLOBAL_SVC-SPServices\' is denied.

Goggling the problem gives me [Clear Cache solution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamesway/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache/)

That cant be it as my error path is not in the `\Config` folder but in the `\PowerPointConversion` folder

However I cant find this folder anywhere. Any help to how to resolve this error or how I can find this folder?

Comment: Check on your application server, you should find this folder. This folder "PowerPointConversion" is usually created manually so you should be having this on your application server.

Comment: @ZakirHC I am on the app-02 server as that is the one throwing the error in the event log. When I try following the path there is nothing in the \SharePoint folder that resembles PowerPointConversion. I did create it 10 min ago and I added the GUID from the error as a folder and I added a Config.ini file to that guid folder. After that I restarted my timer service. Still no luck on polupating it.

Comment: how many server in the farm? On which server the PowerPoint conversion service is running?